# how to change table column sort icon in jhipster and font awesome app

Tags: angularjs, font-awesome, jhipster

I have a webapp generated using JHipster so it has AngularJS at UI side and font awesome for icons.

I have few pages showing data in tables which also support sorting on various columns. But the sorting icon showed on column header is not much intuitive to tell whether the column is sorted ascending or descending. And I don't think that even gets changed on click.

[image]

How can I change those icons to something better like long up arrow for descending sort and long down arrow for ascending sort.
Right now I am using the below code in TH element

```
<th jhiSortBy="name"><span>Name</span> <fa-icon class="grid-icon" [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon></th>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you see both arrows it means the column is unsorted. If you click on a column you are sorting ascending or descending based on that column and you'll see only the up pointing or the down pointing arrow displayed accordingly. They do work as intended.

Regarding font awesome alternatives, you can visit https://web3canvas.com/font-awesome-alternatives/ or google for 'font awesome alternatives'

Nikos